# SSRS - highlight Today's date in range bar chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, gridlines

I'm developing a SSRS report with **Range bar chart**

The range is **Date** and the values are

```
StartDate: DateAdd("yyyy",-3,today())
EndDate: DateAdd("yyyy",2,today())
```

So I get the output like this 
[image: Range bar with Date as range]

How can I highlight today's date in the chart? 
Have the gridline show only for Today??

like this,
[image: With Today's grid highlighted]

Is there a way to do it? I tried setting the **Interval offset** to `DateDiff("d",StartDate,Today())` 
But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't really understand your desired result or what your data looks like.  Could you post some more info, maybe a pic of the chart?

Comment: @mmarie Images added

Comment: There could be multiple ways of doing it. But tell me first: how the data would look in the future and what does Axis1 hold? Also what is the `SQL` dataset for this report? Probably that would help.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti it is a "range bar chart" where the range is "date" which takes the parameters for axis min and max values... The dataset basically holds timeline information of various projects...

Comment: Is there data for every date between the start and end date? There could be cases where "today" there is no project data available.

Comment: I guess what I mean is: Is the category group for your bar chart 'Date' or Year or Month or Quarter etc?

Comment: There is no category group. The dataset has 3 fields... Project name, start and finish date... I just want to know the timelines for each project... With today's date highlight of some way...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69140/discussion-between-sourav-agasti-and-damseldeebi).

Comment: The category group is "Project_Name"